# Volver a página anterior sin cerrar sesión ni perder datos cargados

Tags: php, javascript, html

estoy realizando una aplicación web, con PHP y algo de Javascipt, en la cual se ingresan y se consultan datos, por lo que los mismos se van pasando de página en página (por método POST), todo esto a partir sesión iniciada con usuario y contraseña. Lo que necesito hacer es retornar a la página anterior (por si el usuario desea modificar un dato mal cargado o realizar otro tipo de acción) lo que me sucede es que si coloco un botón con un href a la página anterior, ésta se muestra sin los datos que se venían cargando, lo explico:

Pag.1 le pasa datos a Pag.2, que muestra un mensaje en caso que desde Pag.1 no se haya enviado algún dato, luego Pag.2 le pasa datos a Pag.3, si aquí quiero volver a Pag.2, me sale dicho mensaje, como que no recibió los datos...o sea se pierden y debo volver a Pag.1 para cargar todo otra vez.

¿Se entendió?. He probado también con history.back() de Javascript, pero como que me mata la sesión. 
Como ya habrán notado no soy muy avezado en el tema. Por eso no trabajé con un framework, (estoy recién empezando con Angular js). Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida. Saludos. 
Voy a colocar un fragmento del código, ya que es muy extenso, traté de hacer esto:

```
<!--Parte final del codigo, nombre de la página control.view.php-->
        <button onclick="goBack()">Volver</button>
    </body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function goBack() {
    window.history.back();
  }
</script>
```

La página en cuestión es llamada de la siguiente forma por la página control.php.

```
<?php session_start();
  if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
    require 'control.view.php';
  } else {
    header('Location: index.php');
  }
?>
```

Comment: Puedes colocar tu código para ver por qué no te está funcionando el history.back? Ya que esto no debería tocar para nada la sesión de php.

Comment: Si David Davila, ahi puse algo, espero que sea explicativo. Saludos y desde ya Gracias.